# Bluetooth Inputstream read multiple messages together

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

After establishing a Bluetooth connection I have called write method 5 times to send the messages btAdapter.write("abc18".getBytes()); same way I am reading the messages by read() method but the problem is read method sometimes reading the multiple messages together. How can I prevent this? See my below client and server code.Server sent the same message 5 times and Client reading the same but the issue is sometimes client reading the multiple messages together.

```
server side code:

 private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
 private final InputStream mmInStream;
 private final OutputStream mmOutStream;
mmOutStream.write(buffer);
String sendMsg = "testing";
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){//Sending same message 5 times.
mmOutStream.write(sendMsg.getBytes());
}

Client side:

private final InputStream mmInStream;
mmBuffer = new byte[1024];
numBytes = mmInStream.read(mmBuffer);
byte[] readBuf = mmBuffer;
String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, numBytes);
Log.d(TAG,"READING MESSAGES MESSAGES::"+readMessage.toString());
```

Comment: You cannot prevent that if you keep sending like you do now. Better send lines. And read lines on receiving side.

Comment: Only write method is available for Bluetooth.

Comment: Of course you can send lines with the write method. The only thing you have to add is a '\n' to your string.

Comment: I tried by appending "\n" to the each message and sending.But read() method sometimes still reading multiple messages.

Comment: If you only change the sending side then of course that does not change anything on the receiving side. Please do as i suggested in my first comment.

Comment: Ok Thanks. This is the one I was waiting for the confirmation.This is working perfectly after changing the server side as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot prevent that if you keep sending like you do now.

Better send lines. And read lines on receiving side.